# Doxygen INHERIT_DOCUMENTATION, override only a single argument

Tags: c++, inheritance, doxygen

I still havn't decided whether using INHERIT_DOCUMENTATION is a good idea or not because you no longer have documentation in the code...however, I'm wondering if I could do something like this with INHERIT_DOCUMENTATION on (I'd like it to work in a mask way)

```
class iA
{
public:
  ///
  ///@brief Base message that every one has
  ///@param bar something something something
  ///@return Confidence interval (see specific implementation for more information)
  ///
  virtual double foo(int bar) = 0;
};

class B : public iA
{
public:
//inherit the full parent message, but override just the return statement

///
///@return Confidence interval, which is just equal to bar
///
virtual double foo(int bar) {return bar;}
};
```

So the effective note on B::foo is:

```
  ///
  ///@brief Base message that every one has
  ///@param bar something something something
  ///@return Confidence interval, which is just equal to bar
  ///
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Did you have a look at commands like \copydoc?